# Getting BAD_EXEC using NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

I need to run asynchronous tasks in my app

I have the following code:

```
- (NSDictionary *)parallelSendSync:(NSDictionary *)requests {

    NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in [requests allKeys]) {
        [_parallelSendQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSDictionary *sendResult = [self send:requests[key] :nil];
           [responseDict setObject:sendResult forKey:key]; //this line sometimes throws BAD_EXEC
         }];

    }
     [_parallelSendQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

    return responseDict.copy;

}
```

`_parallelSendQueue` accepts max 5 concurrent operations

unfortunately this works only part of the time, sometimes it works OK, and sometimes it throws BAD_EXEC

what could be the reason for the bad exec ?

Comment: Show the complete crash log.

Comment: unfortunately it just gets stuck, and does not provide me a crash log

Comment: This code shouldnt work anyway I expect the crash is actually outside of this and you are refrencing the return NSDictionary, which may or may not have stuff as it gets filled async but you return it immediatley ? A better solution would be to subclass NSOperation (very simple) and override "main" and pass in a completion block that returns a NSDic.

Comment: That isn't what you say in your question.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 that does not happen because of `[_parallelSendQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that multiple threads are using the same object which can lead to memory corruption for non-threadsafe objects.

You have two options:

- Lock the object you are using from multiple threads or a parallel queue so only one operation can change it at a time
- Dispatch to one specific thread or serial queue that owns the shared object and change it from there (but beware, if you dispatch to the same thread that is currently calling `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` the program is deadlocked)

I think the best solution in your case is locking:

```
- (NSDictionary *)parallelSendSync:(NSDictionary *)requests {

    NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in [requests allKeys]) {
        [_parallelSendQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSDictionary *sendResult = [self send:requests[key] :nil];
            // synchronized locks the object so there is no memory corruption
            @synchronized(responseDict) {
              [responseDict setObject:sendResult forKey:key];
            }
         }];
    }
     [_parallelSendQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

    return responseDict.copy;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have five tasks running in parallel which try to change the some dictionary then a crash is to be expected. Changing responseDict must be done using @synchronized. NSMutableDictionary is not thread safe.